# Master/Backup not functioning correctly, Keepalived

Tags: centos7, keep-alive

Last night this was working correctly but since this morning it seems the roles of the two nodes have been switched. The backup web server is being used by default and when it goes down the primary server is used, but as soon as server2 comes back up it switches back to that.

Both servers are running on CENTOS7 and use NGINX. Here is the config files for both:

SRV1:

```
global_defs {
   notification_email {
   root@webserver-01.example.com
   }
   notification_email_from root@webserver-01.example.com
   smtp_server 127.0.0.1
   smtp_connect_timeout 30
   router_id LVS_DEVEL
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface ens192
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 101 #used in election, 101 for master & 100 for backup
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 1111
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        172.20.25.205/24
    }
}
```

SRV2:

```
global_defs {
   notification_email {
  root@webserver-02.example.com
   }
   notification_email_from root@webserver-02.example.com
   smtp_server 127.0.0.1
   smtp_connect_timeout 30
   router_id LVS_DEVEL
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface ens192
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 100 #used in election, 101 for master & 100 for backup
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 1111
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        172.20.25.205/24
    }
}
```

Is there something obviously incorrect there? Thank you.